# Extracting HTML elements values using their classes

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I have looked at the solution provided in this link [Extract Table from Webpage in Excel using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54473243/extract-table-from-webpage-in-excel-using-vba)  and it was very helpful. But I need to extract the elements with certain classes in each HTML Table cells(td).

1. The URL is: https://www.betfair.com/exchange/plus/football/competition/11997260
2. The HTML table class is: coupon-table
3. The price to extract is nested inside cells. It is in the Span element using the "bet-button-price" class. That's the data I need extracted into each cell in the Excel sheet.

Here's a screenshot of the table structure:

[image]

I would be grateful to receive any help to extract those prices in each cell into the sheet.

```
Public Sub GetInfo()
Const URL As String = "https://www.betfair.com/exchange/plus/football/competition/11997260"
Dim html As HTMLDocument, hTable As HTMLTable, ws As Worksheet, headers()
headers = Array("Countries", "Prices")
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set html = New HTMLDocument
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", URL, False
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With
 Set hTable = html.querySelector("table.coupon-table")
Dim Td As Object, Tr As Object, r As Long, c As Long

r = 1
With ws
    .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
    For Each Tr In hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        r = r + 1: c = 1
        If r > 3 Then
            For Each Td In Tr.getElementsByClassName("bet-button-price")
                .Cells(r - 2, c) = IIf(c = 2, "'" & Td.innerText, Td.innerText)
                c = c + 1
            Next
        End If
    Next
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: It would be really helpful if you posted the code you have tried and specify the exact problems that you're having with it.

Comment: That's the code I'm trying to make work. Please check the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the same endpoint the page uses to update those values which returns json. Then use a json parser to extract the values you want.

I use [jsonconverter.bas](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas) - you add the code from that link to a module called JsonConverter then go VBE > Tools > References > Add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

In VBA for json the `[]` denotes a collection accessed by `For Each` or index, the `{}` represents a dictionary you can access by key or `For Each` over.

I store results in an array and write out in one go to sheet for efficiency. You could write out to `Activesheet.Cells(2,1)` and then add headers, if wanted, in row 1.

You can view an example response json [here](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=bbb824c2b11e456fba78a0dd0a62eb3d).

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetPrices()
    Dim s As String, json As Object, p As String

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.betfair.com/www/sports/exchange/readonly/v1/bymarket?_ak=nzIFcwyWhrlwYMrh&alt=json&currencyCode=GBP&locale=en_GB&marketIds=1.157348157,1.157348529,1.157347785,1.157347909,1.157348405,1.157348653,1.157348281,1.157349025,1.159492425,1.157348777,1.157348033,1.157348901,1.157350197,1.157350445,1.157351280,1.157349949&rollupLimit=10&rollupModel=STAKE&types=MARKET_STATE,MARKET_RATES,MARKET_DESCRIPTION,EVENT,RUNNER_DESCRIPTION,RUNNER_STATE,RUNNER_EXCHANGE_PRICES_BEST,RUNNER_METADATA,MARKET_LICENCE,MARKET_LINE_RANGE_INFO", False
        .send
        s = .responseText
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(s)
    End With

    Dim runners As Object, runner As Object, results(), r As Long
    Set runners = json("eventTypes")(1)("eventNodes")

    ReDim results(1 To runners.Count, 1 To 7)
    For Each runner In runners
        r = r + 1
        results(r, 1) = runner("event")("eventName")
        results(r, 2) = runner("marketNodes")(1)("runners")(1)("exchange")("availableToBack")(1)("price")
        results(r, 3) = runner("marketNodes")(1)("runners")(1)("exchange")("availableToLay")(1)("price")
        results(r, 4) = runner("marketNodes")(1)("runners")(3)("exchange")("availableToBack")(1)("price")
        results(r, 5) = runner("marketNodes")(1)("runners")(3)("exchange")("availableToLay")(1)("price")
        results(r, 6) = runner("marketNodes")(1)("runners")(2)("exchange")("availableToBack")(1)("price")
        results(r, 7) = runner("marketNodes")(1)("runners")(2)("exchange")("availableToLay")(1)("price")
    Next
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
End Sub
```

---

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

have you tried getElementByClassName("yourclassname")?

Comment: No I haven't. Can you please provide a working example?

Comment: sure. go to the next link to see how to use it and even try it online with examples. [link]https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp

Comment: Couldn't get it to work. Can you edit my code here pls?