# How to extract data from HTML divs into Excel

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am trying to extract the details in this webpage and they seem to be under certain "divs" with "selection-left" and "selection-right" right. I haven't found a way to successfully pull it yet. 
This is the URL - https://sports.ladbrokes.com/en-af/betting/golf/golf-all-golf/us-masters/2020-us-masters/228648232/

And here is an image of what I want to extract. I want to copy the competition name and each participant and score.
[image]

I have tried using QHar's approach in this link - [How to extract values from nested divs using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57768998/how-to-extract-values-from-nested-divs-using-vba). But I'm getting errors along this line - 
     ReDim results(1 To countries.Length / 2, 1 To 4)

Here is the code I've been trying to make work

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetData()
Dim html As HTMLDocument, ws As Worksheet, countries As Object, scores As Object, results(), i As 
Long, r As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1"): Set html = New HTMLDocument: r = 1

With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "https://sports.ladbrokes.com/en-af/betting/golf/golf-all-golf/us-masters/2020-us-masters/228648232/", False
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

Set participant = html.querySelectorAll(".market-content .selection-left"): Set scores = html.querySelectorAll("..market-content .selection-right")
ReDim results(1 To countries.Length / 2, 1 To 4)

For i = 0 To participant.Length - 1 Step 2
    results(r, 1) = participant.item(i).innerText: results(r, 2) = "'" & scores.item(i).innerText

    r = r + 1
Next
ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 4) = Array("Competition", "Participant", "Score")
ws.Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
End Sub
```

I will need help to make this code work

Comment: What if `countries.Length` is not an even number? Or zero?  "I'm getting errors" is not a very useful description of what you see when running your code - what's the exact error message?

Comment: It seems that you declare variables "countries", but you do not set its value so it is equal to nothing when you try to use its length property.

Comment: Your best bet here would be selenium basic as content is rendered dynamically. You could try mimicking the POST request the page makes but it is not simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content is dynamically added so will not be present in your current request format; hence your error as you have a nodeList of Length 0. You could try making POST requests as the page does but it doesn't look like a quick and easy bit of coding. I would go with browser automation, if this is a small project, so that js can run on the page and you can click the show more button. You will need a wait condition for the page to have properly loaded. I use the presence of the show more button.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetOddsIE()
    Dim d As InternetExplorer, odds As Object, names As Object, i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet, results(), competition As String

    Set d = New InternetExplorer
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Const URL = "https://sports.ladbrokes.com/en-af/betting/golf/golf-all-golf/us-masters/2020-us-masters/228648232/"

    With d
        .Visible = False
        .Navigate2 URL
        While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
        With .Document.getElementsByClassName("expandable-below-container-button")
            Do
                DoEvents
            Loop While .Length = 0  'wait for element to be present
            .Item(0).Click 'click on show more
        End With

        Set names = .Document.getElementsByClassName("selection-left-selection-name")
        Set odds = .Document.getElementsByClassName("odds-convert")
        competition = .Document.getElementsByClassName("league")(0).innerText

        ReDim results(1 To names.Length, 1 To 3)

        For i = 0 To names.Length - 1
            results(i + 1, 1) = competition
            results(i + 1, 2) = names.Item(i).innerText
            results(i + 1, 3) = "'" & odds.Item(i).innerText
        Next
        .Quit
    End With
    ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 3) = Array("Competition", "Participant", "Score")
    ws.Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
End Sub
```

---

Comment: Good result as always. What if I dont want the browser to display?

Comment: d.visible = False