# Why does querySelectorAll return an object that is JScriptTypeInfo, which can then be treated as a string, instead of a nodeList?

Tags: vba, web-scraping, types, scriptcontrol

Whilst answering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58022484/how-to-extract-data-from-html-divs-into-excel/58023388#58023388) question I noted some odd, to me, behaviour. In the code from that answer, shown below, I was expecting the variables `names` to be a static nodeList: `Object\DispStaticNodeList`. This is the usual return for [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectoraLL) with VBA MSHTML.HTMLDocument class.

From the [API documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

> The Document method querySelectorAll() returns a static (not live)
>   NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the
>   specified group of selectors.

However, in this case the return in Locals is `Object`, and when using TypeName(names) is `JScriptTypeInfo`. I have previously read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711112/in-excel-vba-on-windows-for-parsed-json-variables-what-is-this-jscripttypeinfo/37711113) impressive post and am passingly familiar with `ScriptControl` but this doesn't explain to me what is going on here.

Why is querySelectorAll returning an `JScriptTypeInfo` Object instead of a static nodeList. And why is this `JScriptTypeInfo` specific to `querySelectorAll` and not `getElementsByClassName`? I feel it must be something to do with class interfaces but what is it about this page that leads to `Object\JScriptTypeInfo` rather than `Object\DispStaticNodeList`?

---

**Other observations:**

1. You can use `getElementsByClassName` just fine:

```
Set names = .getElementsByClassName("selection-left-selection-name")
'?typename(names) >> DispHTMLElementCollection
```

2. The object passes the IsObject test and can be used with Set but subsequently can be treated as a String:

```
Debug.Print IsObject(names)  '>> True
Debug.Print names    '>> "[object HTMLDivElement],[object HTMLDivElement],[object HTMLDivElement],....."
```

I assume it is something to do with there being an actual object returned but a default member call being made with `Debug.Print names`. But for this to work we I assume we are no longer getting an array of objects as a return. Otherwise, it would be chained default call to .defaultMember.defaultMember.  The linked QA by @SMeaden states:

> JScriptTypeInfo is something to show in the VBA IDE watch window and
>   the return of the VBA function TypeName() but which really hides a
>   number of objects that can be found in JScript.dll. I suppose it can
>   be described as polymorphic, perhaps better to describe it as late
>   binding. To view capabilities use Tools-References and browse to
>   JScript.dll.

In that case, how do I inspect the the default member (I am on 64 bit machine)? I assume I can't add in ScriptControl dlls as I think they require 32 bit? These later points are more musings.

3. I had wondered if it was to do with `querySelectorAll` using css selectors but I noted the following:
   With Python selenium + IE using Css selectors (as I cannot test with VBA Selenium Basic) I do no see this behaviour though the class implementation is `webElement`. I get the expected `<class 'list'>`  as a return. I include a script for VBA selenium I cant test but should work as a test for others to run.

---

**Code to reproduce:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetOddsIE()
    Dim d As InternetExplorer, names As Object, t as Date, button As Object, ws As Worksheet

    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10
    Set d = New InternetExplorer
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Const URL = "https://sports.ladbrokes.com/en-af/betting/golf/golf-all-golf/us-masters/2020-us-masters/228648232/"

    With d
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 URL
        While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .Document
            t = Timer
            Do
                DoEvents
                On Error Resume Next
                Set button = .querySelector(".expandable-below-container-button span")
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
            Loop While button Is Nothing         'wait for element to be present
            If button Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
            button.Click                         'click on show more

            Set names = .querySelectorAll(".selection-left-selection-name")
            Debug.Print IsObject(names)
            Debug.Print TypeName(names)
            Debug.Print names        
          End With             
        Stop
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Css selectors via Python selenium + IE:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

d = webdriver.Ie()
d.get('https://sports.ladbrokes.com/en-af/betting/golf/golf-all-golf/us-masters/2020-us-masters/228648232/')
WebDriverWait(d,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".expandable-below-container-button"))).click()
names = d.find_elements_by_css_selector('.selection-left-selection-name')
print(type(names))
d.quit()
```

Gives

`>> <class 'list'>`

**Untested VBA selenium with IE (I cannot test this):**

```
Public Sub GetOdds() 'Not tested
    Dim d As WebDriver, names As Object, button As Object, t As Date
    Set d = New IEDriver
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Const URL = "https://sports.ladbrokes.com/en-af/betting/golf/golf-all-golf/us-masters/2020-us-masters/228648232/"

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get URL
        t = Timer
        Do
            DoEvents
            On Error Resume Next
            Set button = .FindElementByCss(".expandable-below-container-button span")
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop While button Is Nothing
        If button Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Set names = .FindElementsByCss(".selection-left-selection-name")
        Debug.Print IsObject(names)
        Debug.Print names.Text '<should fail if webElementsCollection
        Stop
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting behaviour indeed. I think your diagnosis of an Object with a default member is correct. What does the object look like in the locals window?

Comment: @Greedo Nothing is shown. As per the linked question I think one way is to inspect is to add jscript libraries but then that becomes an issue for 64 bit. And why does this only happen under the IE example with the Microsoft Internet Controls library (and only with querySelector?) You can use getElementsByClassName just fine.